# MUI DataGridPro is rerendered because of not cached click handler depending on row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, memoization

My application has a DataGridPro component with rows containing a toggle button to switch their hiding/showing state (used in another part of the application) by performing an API call. A column with a menu to perform edit/delete operations on a single row is present. In particular, when the *delete* item is clicked a confirmation dialog is opened and an handler to the delete method to perform on acceptance is passed. This method takes the row as input and calls the delete API. This method is retrieved outside the component via a React hook.

The problem is that the table is rendered again when changing the row state because of this method: if I change the columns widths or order and then click on the toggle button the initial state is restored.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
export const useTableColumns = (): GridColDef<RowType>[] => {
    const openDeleteDialog = useOpenDeleteDialog();
    const deleteAPI = useDeleteAPI();

    return useMemo(() => {
      const actionsColumn = createActionsColumn<RowType>(
        ({ row }) => [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            label="Delete"
            onClick={() => {
              openDeleteDialog({
                onConfirm: () => {
                  deleteAPI([row]);
                },
              });
            }}
          />,
        ],
      );
      return [actionsColumn, ...otherColumns];
    }, [deleteAPI, openDeleteDialog]);
  };
```

I tried to memoize the React hook like this:

`const deleteAPI = useCallback(useDeleteAPI, [])`

and passing it to `onConfirm` like this:

`onConfirm: () => deleteAPI()([row])`

This solves the problem of the columns widths and order persistence but breaks the *delete* button as when I click it I'm calling a React hook inside a component.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!